# 30V on 120 circuit - swapped dishwashers and circuit dropped to 30V

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel, 120-240v

Situation: replaced dishwasher. Turned off the breaker first. The original DW is 100% fine, just doing an upgrade. I did not measure the voltage on the wires. New one - connect to existing wires, dedicated line, and nothing. I hot wired the new DW and it works connected to a different circuit. The dedicated run measures 30V on one meter, and 3V on another, and both meters read ~120V when plugged into an outlet. I stripped the wire back and did not get different result. Tomorrow I will pull open the panel and check for neutral, corroded bus, maybe a loose wire. Why would I get 30V when all i did was swap DWs' and wire is 20 year old ROMEX, 14 or 12 G. I am guessing I am at the breaker or in the panel issue? Thoughts? Bad luck? Thank you master experts!

Comment: What make and model is your breaker panel? Also, does either of your meters have a "Low Z" function on it?

Comment: Checking a neutral ok but you would have 120 to ground. I would be looking for a hot wire that pulled loose from a wire nut if the breaker did not trip. The voltage could be phantom as the low z comment from 3 phase.

Comment: What brand panel?  There are a few out there that have known issues but most will function mechanically (off / on by hand).

Comment: Good day and thank you for your inquiry back. 11/98 install of a Cutler Hammer panel and i checked all the breakers are the same MFG. I appreciate the clarification on maybe a Black lead is loose. I am suspecting the wiring in the wall at a switch may be causing the problem, even though the DW is a dedicated run, I think all the wires from the panel arrive at the same switch junction. I will be diving in in about 6 hours from now. Real life job is in the way.

Comment: Thank you - issue resolved. Bad circuit breaker. It tripped but still allowed a trickle of energy to transmit. That has me concerned. Should not have been reading 30V. Combine this with a mistake made by an electrician 14 + years ago when he rewired my panel for an HVAC upgrade - he moved circuits around and did not change face labels. Spent a good chunk of time yesterday making sure all labels are accurate.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the issue was resolved (see comments) and the post abandoned.